dataframe withColumn printing out column name rather value
Hi i have the following dataframe with a derived column (withColumn)
working with a month day, if the month day is 1-9 then put a 0 before value.
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, to_date, expr, when

from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType


df = (
spark.read.option("header", "True")
.option("delimiter", ",")
.option("inferSchema", "True")
.csv("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00000")
)



#dff = df.withColumn("DayofMonthFormatted", 
when(df.DayofMonth.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), "Yes").otherwise("No"))

dff = df.withColumn("DayofMonthFormatted", 
when(df.DayofMonth.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), "0" + 
str(df.DayofMonth)).otherwise(df.DayofMonth))
    
display(dff['DayofMonth', 'DayofMonthFormatted'])



#dff =  df.withColumn('DayDate', 
to_date(concat('Year','Month','DayofMonth'),'yyyyMMdd'))

#display(dff)

i know I'm very close but struggling to see what it is i can do.
see output for below


Resolved using format_string
dff = df.withColumn("DayofMonthFormatted", when(df.DayofMonth.isin([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), format_string("0%d", df.DayofMonth)).otherwise(df.DayofMonth))
